# What does the first argument of the imp.load_source method do?

Tags: python, module

I'm reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) SO question about importing modules from absolute path. An answer suggest to use following code:

```
import imp
foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

I want to import file from dir which has following structure (it is package):

```
__int__.py
model_params.py
```

I've done this:

```
import01 = imp.load_source('module.name', '/home/wakatana/experiments/model_params/model_params.py')
```

Now I can access variables within `model_params.py` via `import01.VARIABLE_NAME`. It seems like equivalent to `import numpy as np`. Where `model_params.py` is like `numpy` and `import01` is like `np`.

I would like to ask what does the first argument of `load_source` method do? `help(imp)` says practically nothing about `load_source` method, e.g. following `help(imp.load_source)` returns `load_source(...)`

Thanks

**EDIT based on behzad.nouri comment**

On documentation page of [load_source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source) is said:

> The name argument is used to create or access a module object.

But when I try to access `module.name` I get an error about not defined module. Also why there is not documentation that can be accessed by `help`, can I install it somehow? I was hoping that documentation is part of the code itself in python, or is it common practice to not have it built-in but rather have it on-line?

Comment: [`imp.load_source`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imp.html) has a bit more info on the topic.

Basically the name that you load the module with will be used in other files that import that module. Even though no `module.name` module exists anywhere in the python path, if you load some module and give it that name, other modules that do a regular `import` with that name will not raise errors and work as expected. Perhaps a small example would illustrate this better:

#### /tmp/test/foo.py

```
value = 1337
```

#### /tmp/test/bar.py

```
from foo.bar import value

def print_val():
    print value
```

#### /tmp/test/run.py

```
import imp
foo = imp.load_source('foo.bar', '/tmp/test/foo.py')

import bar

bar.print_val()
```

As expected, you get `1337` printed to the screen. If the name was not `foo.bar`, the import would have failed in `bar.py` since no such module actually exists.

This method can actually be used for monkey patching as it would override imports inside 3rd party modules.

Comment: Thank you, the example says it all. Could person who give an down vote explain the reasons? Thank you.

Comment: writing `from foo import value` also works in `bar.py`. Could you explain why `foo.bar` is needed in `bar.py`?

Answer (score 1):

[From documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html)

> imp.load_source(name, pathname[, file]):
>
> Load and initialize a module implemented as a Python source file and return its module object. If the module was already initialized, it will be initialized again. **The name argument is used to create or access a module object**. The pathname argument points to the source file. The file argument is the source file, open for reading as text, from the beginning. It must currently be a real file object, not a user-defined class emulating a file. Note that if a properly matching byte-compiled file (with suffix .pyc or .pyo) exists, it will be used instead of parsing the given source file